# how to get particular record by using where condition in webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I want to return a particular record from the webservice. Still what i have successfully done is, got all the records by the following code:

```
 SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataAdapter adap;
    DataSet ds;
    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet Getmember()
    {

        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SQLDOTNET\MSSQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=doctor;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;pwd=test123#;");
        adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblusers", con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds, "tblusers");
        return ds;
    }
```

Now i want to get a particular record by Emailid for that i have tried the following code:

```
SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataAdapter adap;
    DataSet ds;
    [WebMethod]
    public DataSet Getmember(String Emailid)
    {
        Emailid = "test@test.com";
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SQLDOTNET\MSSQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=doctor;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;pwd=test123#;");
        adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblusers where EmailAddress=" + Emailid, con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds, "tblusers");
        return ds;
    }
```

But this code throwing the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'test@test.com'.
```

Please help me..

Comment: See [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose string literals in single quotes in SQL:

```
"select * from tblusers where EmailAddress = '" + Emailid + "'"
```

**But this leaves you open to SQL injection attacks and is not recommended.** (Examine what would happen if `Emailid` were set to `"' OR 1=1 OR ''='"`.)

You should specify `Emailid` as a parameter value instead:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblusers where EmailAddress = ?");
cmd.Parameters.Add(Emailid);
adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
```

Answer (score 0):

change the

```
Emailid = "test@test.com";
```

to

```
Emailid = "'test@test.com'";
```

Note the extra single quotes arount emailid

Answer (score 0):

At first you should use SQL parameters... not the plain SQL queries so better check [SQL Parameters](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06)

```
adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblusers where EmailAddress=" + Emailid, con);
```

should be changed to

```
adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblusers where EmailAddress='" + Emailid + "'", con);
```

You miss to have "'" in you query .. Better you look at the [statement syntax](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S)...

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this would help cause I havent use C # for some time

I think your error goes on this part

```
select * from tblusers where EmailAddress=" + Emailid
```

Try changing it to

```
"select * from tblusers where EmailAddress='" + Emailid + "'"
```